# Can you get the actual differences between two git commits?

Tags: git

In the scenario where the first commit, is adding file X, second commit, you remove X and the third commit you re-add it.

If you run git diff, then you get X deleted, X added.

Is there a way to analyse this set of changes and get the result, "no change" ?

I am actually interested in the line changes, in my real example, I get this response:

```
index 5988d3c..eaf3238 100644
--- a/.babelrc
+++ b/.babelrc
@@ -1,3 +1,3 @@
-{
-  "presets": ["es2015", "stage-0"]
-}
+{
+  "presets": ["es2015", "stage-0"]
+}
```

which seems to show the exact same lines added **and** subtracted.

## Edit:

Here is the output of diff -R

```
--- b/.babelrc
+++ a/.babelrc
@@ -1,3 +1,3 @@
-{
-  "presets": ["es2015", "stage-0"]
-}
+{^M
+  "presets": ["es2015", "stage-0"]^M
+}^M
```

Comment: `git diff HEAD~2` will give you an empty result. `git diff HEAD~1` will give you the file you re-added. Not sure I understand your question.

Comment: @JulienLopez I have updated my question to show the issue I am facing, the difference seems to show the exact same text added **and** subtracted

Comment: This looks like a whitespace issue, what do you get with `diff -R`?

Comment: @dimid that seems to be it, is there a way to ignore these changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do `git diff [first commit] [third commit]` and this will return no difference.

For example here is the `git log` of my test repository.

```
commit 368c6c0bc4169b8f482761b036da2284f937579d
Author: Adam
Date:   Fri May 6 10:17:45 2016 +0100

    Edited file back.

commit 54d9885f860b56c34718387206397c703eb37b36
Author: Adam
Date:   Fri May 6 10:16:51 2016 +0100

    Edited file.

commit 681f117fd095c7a99d631a1819db855d7fd9e6e8
Author: Adam
Date:   Fri May 6 10:16:09 2016 +0100

    Added file.
```

When I compare the first and third commits using `git diff 681f117fd095c7a99d631a1819db855d7fd9e6e8 368c6c0bc4169b8f482761b036da2284f937579d` the result is empty.

However if I compare the first and second commit using `git diff 681f117fd095c7a99d631a1819db855d7fd9e6e8 54d9885f860b56c34718387206397c703eb37b36` the result is:

```
diff --git a/file.txt b/file.txt
index c9a0e4f..76af740 100644
--- a/file.txt
+++ b/file.txt
@@ -1,6 +1,6 @@
 I won't edit this line.

-I will edit this line.
+I have edited this line.

 I won't edit this line.
```

If you aren't getting an empty change set but the lines read the same then there must be some difference in characters within the line, for example a tab being used instead of a space or a different line ending.

You can use `git diff -w` to ignore white space when performing the diff. Documentation: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, please see my updated question to see a real example of what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply try using following command It will show you difference between two commits..

```
git diff first_commit_id(hash) second_commit_id(hash)
```

you can find commit_id(hash) by typing `git log` command..

```
Example:

git diff effd192760b957b9a65b011249c122f8434ba7cf effd192760b957b9a67b011249c122f8434ba7cf
```

Answer (score 0):

As I've said in the comments, it's a whitespace issue. Use `dos2unix` to get rid of `^M`. If you want to ignore whitespace use `git diff -w`, although I wouldn't recommend it.